# Javascript deleting current word from string and everything after it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a series of strings like this:

```
http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=2
http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=3
http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=4
http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=5
```

etc

I need a way to remove the `'&wpv_paged='`  part of the string as well as everything after it

My question is, should I use `regex` or `split()` for this and if so, how would I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What about `http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=2&param2=abc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
&wpv_paged=\d+.*$
```

You can try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/7

Comment: This will not work if an additional parameter is added after the wpv-paged parameter, like so: http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/6

Comment: @sebbzzz will do now :)

Comment: Can I use str.replace() with this regex?

Comment: @user2028856 use regex.replace()

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=2".split("&wpv_");
```

`url[0]` will give you the segment of the url before the "&wpv_"-part

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want for `http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=2&param2=abc`

```
"http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=2&param2=abc".split("&wpv_")[0]
```

gives:

```
http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde
```

and

```
"http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&wpv_paged=2&param2=abc".replace(/&wpv_paged=\d+/, '')
```

gives:

```
http://mytestdomain.com/bla/abc/?zde&param2=abc
```